# Clear buffer independent of the operating system

Tags: c++, c, buffer

I'd like to know how I can do to clear the standard input buffer, regardless of the operating system I'm using.
I know that in Windows I can use `fflush` and Linux `fpurge`, but I would like a single solution that works for both (does not necessarily have to be a function).

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` only works on buffered input streams (like disk files), it does not work on pipes and terminals.  In C++, you can use `std::cin.ignore()` to ignore buffered unread input, eg: `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n')`

Comment: @Remy: Doesn't `std::cin.ignore` also ignore unread input not yet buffered, until it finds the delimiter character?

Comment: @rici: yes. To clear just the previously buffered data, you would likely have to access `std::cin`'s underlying `streambuf` object directly and read from it until it has nothing to read without going back to the terminal for more data.

Comment: And for C, what is the solution?

Comment: @WesleyAlves: There isn't really a cross-platform solution. There is `fpurge()` on Linux, but no equivalent on Windows (unless you count `FlushConsoleInputBuffer()`, which flushes what the user has already typed in the console that hasn't been read in by your app yet). You could try using `freopen()` to close and reopen stdin, if your compiler's RTL implements it.

Comment: There are also `ioctl` invocations you can use on Unix/Linux to clear the terminal input buffer (if it's terminal input you care about, naturally).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I think what you meant to write is along the lines of "`fflush` is only guaranteed to *do anything* for files with which the last operation was a write"... Please tell me you meant to write that, right?

Comment: @Sebivor: `fflush()` is defined only for output streams, not input streams.  However, Linux does implement `fflush()` for input streams of seekable files.

Comment: @RemyLebeau as of POSIX.1-2008, fflush() is defined to remove unread characters from an input stream.

Comment: The buffer is provided by the operating system so you can't do anything with it independent of the operating system...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you mean by "clear the standard input buffer", this may do:

```
int c;
do c = getchar(); while (c != EOF && c != '\n');
```

This absorbs up to EOF or a newline, whichever comes first.

The main situation where this wouldn't be what you want is if you don't want it to maybe block until the user presses Enter.  In that case, you're SOL; there is no universal mechanism.

Comment: Nitpick: that would be line feed, not carriage return (which is `\r`).

Comment: @NominalAnimal Right back at ya, `'\n'` in C isn't required to be a line feed; in fact, the character "line feed" isn't required to exist (though oddly enough, carriage returns are required). The C standard describes characters with the value `'\n'` as "newline characters"...

Comment: @Sebivor: Wrong. `\n` in C is "newline", and `\r` is "carriage return", according to C11 5.2.2p2. However, Unicode and ASCII call `\n` line feed. That said, I do prefer "newline" over "line feed" myself.

Comment: I learned my terminology from 80s micros (yeah, I'm that old) and they consistently called it a "carriage return," because everyone writing the documentation was familiar with mechanical typewriters.  "Newline" is perhaps the better term in the context of C, though.

Comment: Yes, I fully agree, *newline* is the best term here for `'\n'`. This is quite a complex set of details, when one gets to the OS level, and that's the only reason I bothered with the nitpick. For example, in POSIXy systems the pseudoterminal layer (tty/pty) maps the `\n` (*newline*) output by programs to `\r\n` (*carriage return* followed by *linefeed*) by default (`ONLCR` termios flag is set by default). There is a clear layer boundary, and when using e.g. curses or "raw" terminal (or writing a master!), this often surprises programmers. Exact terms help with untangling this mess, I believe.